# How to get Array Header names of this JSON

Tags: jquery

I am parsing a JSON Response

```
var response =
   [
    {
        "Home": [
            {
                "name": "Ohris"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Office": [
            {
                "name": "Swaghat"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Location X": [
            {
                "name": "Loc1"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I have tried it this way

```
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
//  alert(JSON.stringify(response[i]));
    alert(response[i]);
}
```

Is it possible to get the Array names ?? that is in this case .

**Home , Office , Location X**

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ktLe1u1e/1/

is this possible , if not i can modify the JSON structure to if needed ??

Comment: You _should_ modify the JSON structure it doesn't really make much sense. That said `response.map(function(el){ return Object.keys(el).pop(); }).join(",")` should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this piece of code inside the loop:

...

```
for (var key in response[i]) {
   alert(' name=' + key );
   // do some more stuff with response[key]
}
```

See the demo result:
http://jsfiddle.net/ktLe1u1e/3/

Comment: Thank you very much , how to access each key elements ?? http://jsfiddle.net/ktLe1u1e/6/

Comment: Thank you very much , you saved my day . I was strugling with debugger for this .

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the inner object in temp variable and then iterate on this with for in loop as below:

```
var op = [];
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
  var temp = response[i];
    for (key in temp){
        op.push(key);
    }
}
alert(op)
```

Comment: Code and explanation should be posted here. A fiddle is just an example reference.

Comment: 1. Link-only answers are not useful. jsFiddle can be offline (or go away entirely), and people shouldn't have to go off-site to get the answer. There's a **reason** SO wouldn't let you post that link as a link (saying quite clearly *"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code."*), please respect that rather than working around it, it's designed this way *for a reason*. 2. Answers with code without explanation are *also* not useful answers.

Comment: Thanks , is it possible to access each array data individually ?? I mean in case if we provide HOME , is it possible to get its relavnat data only ??

Comment: You can do it by it's index. i.e. for HOME:
response[op.indexOf('HOME')].HOME

Comment: yes that looks fine , but how can i get only the value ?? (Ohris) only